# Javascript: sample rate ignored on constructing an AudioContext

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audiocontext

Why

```
let context = new AudioContext({
  latencyHint: "interactive",
  sampleRate: 44100
});

console.log(context)
```

gives a sample rate of 48000 samples, while I want it to be running at 44 Khz?

Chrome 71.0.3578.98, mac os 10.14.2

Reference: [AudioContextOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContextOptions)

Comment: Which browser? I am getting a fine 44100 with chrome Version 71.0.3578.80 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

Comment: @Jankapunkt Chrome 71.0.3578.98, mac os 10.14.2

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is not yet implemented in Chrome. Here is a link to the relevant bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=432248.

It's implemented in Firefox though.

If you don't specify the sampleRate or the browser doesn't support setting the sampleRate it should pick the sampleRate of your default audio output device. This might change over time if you have for example an external sound card.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Also it seems not to be consistent, sometimes I got 48 khz and other times 44 khz, on the same device

Comment: How come that I get a correct result? My chrome build ist posted below the question

Comment: @revy I added a paragraph about the default behavior. But maybe you are experiencing another bug (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=754420) which seems to be present in the current version of Chrome.

Comment: Does not work in firefox (121.0.1) too

Comment: @JRichardsz please consider filing a bug for Firefox if `console.log(new AudioContext({sampleRate: 44100}).sampleRate);` doesn't log 44100 on your machine. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=Web%20Audio